# What is best Practice to use Locks in Java (Interview)?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, java.util.concurrent

I was asked this in interview: Pseudo code is Ok

```
//Assume you have a list or A Queue
//1 - How do you make Sure pushing to list is safe?
//1 - My Ans: 
        void push(Element e){
            Synchronized(this){
               list.push(e);
              }
             }
//2- Interviewer said Ok, there is better way to do this without Synchronized word
          void push(Element e){
              writeLock.Lock();
              list.push(e);
              writeLock.UnLock();
             }
//3- He said Ok, but wouldn't work if there are 16 threads, How can I make sure only one thread can write?  His answer was more like a "Semaphore"
       void push(Element e){
             readLock.lock(16), //meaning get read lock on all 16 thrds
              writeLock.Lock(); //then allow to write
              list.push(e);
              writeLock.UnLock();
              readLock.Unlock()
             }
```

I am not sure I understood his solution at #3, Anyone cares to explain and elaborate?

Comment: If he's talking about [`ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html), he's wrong. "The read lock may be held simultaneously by multiple reader threads, so long as there are no writers. The write lock is exclusive. "

Comment: It's unclear what `readLock.lock(16)` is supposed to mean. The question can't be generalized. The answer depends 100% on what the semantics of the specific class are. You'll have to edit your question with a more specific example, otherwise there is no answer.

Comment: I think that is a pseudo code. Question is about the concept

Comment: @HamedMoghaddam The question can't be about the concept. The correct answer depends entirely on the semantics of the API. The fact that there exists an API in Java with different semantics proves it.

Comment: @EJP In the first line of question I see "Pseudo Code is OK". Which is not clear in the context but seems to me user1529412 means it is not the exact code. That is why I think this code is not necessarily the exact code asked in the interview and it could have been a conceptual question

Comment: Correct, interviewer used this example as a psudeo code. He didn't care whether this was in C++ or Java, he mainly wanted to get the point across that semephore has many threads that can read and need to all be locked when doing a write...readLock.lock(16) just psuedo for to indicate a read lock on all 16 threads..

Answer (score 2):

Idea is readers can read only if there is no write is going on. In other words, reading is synchronization free. So 16 thread can concurrently read.
However, When you want to write you lock everything (both read and write processes) and only do the writing. Interviewer might have taken the idea from the  ConcurrentHashMap since default value for concurrencyLevel of that is 16.

I suggest you look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html